# Send data to a Channel from a callback method (Spring Integration)

Tags: spring-integration

I have a method that is called as a callback from some communication library when data are received.

Using Spring Integration, I would like to send data to a specific Channel that will be later picked up by some Sender and some Database Recorder. These two may work in parallel. How could I do it?

I prefer not to use XML for anything.

Comment: Sorry, the question isn't clear. Try to rephrase it and/or share some code on the matter. Why can't you just send from that callback to and existing channel?

Comment: @ArtemBilan that is exactly what I need, to send into an existing channel. Since it is my first try on integration, how do I create that "existing channel"? Also, rephrased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> These two may work in parallel.

For this purpose Spring Integration provides [PublishSubscribeChannel](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-channels-section.html#channel-configuration-pubsubchannel). With its `executor` option you really can make subscribers working in parallel.

> I would like to send data to a specific Channel

So, just do that from that callback method.

You can consider to use [Messaging Gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#gateway) for dependency injection instead of direct channel injection for sending.

That way you will call the gateway's method from that callback and the data will be send to predefined `PublishSubscribeChannel` channel for distribution between its subscribers.

> how do I create that "existing channel"

That's all about Spring and its inversion of control implementation.

You may consider to consult existing [Spring Integration Samples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples) for ideas.

Comment: Thank you Artem, would it be possible to see the code about sending data to channel? I am confused about how channel must be known to callback method.

Comment: The object with that method must be a bean in Spring. So, that way you easily can inject any other existing beans, e.g. `MessageChannel`  for sending from the method.

Comment: Do you mean I can use this to make a channel? https://gist.github.com/arthurtsang/5268129

Comment: That is good code, but still unclear why you don't do that via `@Bean`...